# How to properly register plugins in Hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, hapi.js

I followed hapi's official website and tried a simple server, but failed: I cannot register plugins,

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({port: 4004});

server.register([require('inert'), require('vision')], (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.start(err => {
        console.log('server started');
    });
});
```

It is throwing foollowing error:

```
/Users/apple/Documents/node_projects/hapijon/testjon/ch4_routes_and_handlers/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:219
        if (plugin.register.register) {                             // Required plugin
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined
    at module.exports.internals.Server.internals.Plugin.register (/Users/apple/Documents/node_projects/hapijon/testjon/ch4_routes_and_handlers/node_modules/hapi/lib/plugin.js:219:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/node_projects/hapijon/testjon/ch4_routes_and_handlers/tess.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Here is my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "accept": "^2.1.4",
    "hapi": "^14.2.0",
    "inert": "^5.0.1",
    "iron": "^5.0.4",
    "vision": "^5.3.0",
    "wreck": "^14.0.2"
  }
```

Comment: Has this question been answered to your satisfaction?  If so, can you please mark one of the answers below as the accepted answer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to v17 docs at https://hapijs.com/api#server.register() :

`await server.register(plugins, [options])`

> Registers a plugin where:
>
> - plugins - one or an array of:
>
>   - a [plugin object](https://hapijs.com/api#plugins).
>   - an object with the following:
>
>     - `plugin` - a plugin object.
>     - `options` - (optional) options passed to the plugin during registration.
>     - `once`, `routes` - (optional) plugin-specific registration options as defined below.
> - options - (optional) registration options (different from the options passed to the registration function):
>
>   - `once` - if `true`, subsequent registrations of the same plugin are skipped without error. Cannot be used with plugin options. Defaults to
>       `false`. If not set to `true`, an error will be thrown the second time a
>       plugin is registered on the server.
>   - `routes` - modifiers applied to each route added by the plugin:
>
>     - `prefix` - string added as prefix to any route path (must begin with `'/'`). If a plugin registers a child plugin the `prefix` is
>         passed on to the child or is added in front of the child-specific
>         prefix.
>     - `vhost` - virtual host string (or array of strings) applied to every route. The outer-most `vhost` overrides the any nested configuration.
>
> Return value: none.

A `plugin object` is an object with the following properties:

> - `register` - (required) the registration function with the signature `async function(server, options)` where:
>
>   - `server - the server object with a plugin-specific`server.realm`.
>   - `options` - any options passed to the plugin during registration via `server.register()`.
> - `name` - (required) the plugin name string. The name is used as a unique key. Published plugins (e.g. published in the npm registry)
>     should use the same name as the name field in their 'package.json'
>     file. Names must be unique within each application.
> - `version` - (optional) plugin version string. The version is only used informatively to enable other plugins to find out the versions
>     loaded. The version should be the same as the one specified in the
>     plugin's 'package.json' file.
> - `multiple` - (optional) if `true`, allows the plugin to be registered multiple times with the same server. Defaults to `false`.
> - `dependencies` - (optional) a string or an array of strings indicating a plugin dependency. Same as setting dependencies via
>     `server.dependency()`.
> - `once` - (optional) if `true`, will only register the plugin once per server. If set, overrides the `once` option passed to
>     `server.register()`. Defaults to no override.

So, for your usage, try:

```
const Inert = require('inert');
const Vision = require('vision');
await server.register([Inert.plugin, Vision.plugin]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would bump version of hapi to latest, the versions of these 2 plugins appear to only work with latest version of hapi.